# How to cout all integers that user entered backwards

Tags: c++

This is the first part that will get integers from user until zero is entered
int n ;

```
for ( int i = 1 ; n != 0 ; i++ ){
    cin >> n ;

}
```

But I have no idea how to print all the given numbers backwards

Comment: You'll have to store more than a single int at a time for this. Have you learned about collections like arrays or `std::vector` yet?

Comment: You'll need to store the numbers, maybe in a `std::vector`?

Comment: Ask your friend how they did it then. I can't see a way that's possible

Comment: can you please explain your way with arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save all input numbers to container (for example [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). And after just make output in other order.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for ( int i = 1 ; n != 0 ; i++ ) {
    cin >> n ;
}

vec.pop_back();

std::copy(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of checking `n != 0` twice per loop iteration, you could just `pop_back` once at the end? Or do `while(true)` and `break`. Lots of small ways to tweak code like this.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes you are right. This is not the only correct decision. The question uses a for loop and I wanted to keep it for clarity.

Comment: You should probably explain the last line. It's quite obtuse for newcomers to the language who haven't seen iterators or algorithms at all, and even to experienced programmers who haven't seen the I/O iterators.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a while loop and a vector

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>     
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    vector <int> v1;
    while(cin>>n)
    {
      if(n==0)
         break;
      
      v1.push_back(n);
    }
    
    //then run the for loop in reverse
    
    for(int i = v1.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout<<v1[i]<<endl;
    }


}
```